# Source code being exposed by AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've tried using the AWS forums to get help but, oh boy, it's hard to get anything over there. In any case, [the original post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=136256&tstart=0) is still there.

Here's the same question.

I deployed a Python (Flask) app using Elastic Beanstalk and the Python container. The directory structure is more or less this (simplified to get to the point):

```
[app root]
  - application.py
  - requirements.txt
  /.ebextensions
      - python-container.config 
  /secrets
      - keys.py
      - secret_logic.py
  /myapp
      - __init__.py
      /static
         - image1.png
         - some-other-file.js
      /services
         - __init__.py
         - some-app-logic.py
```

I found that any file in my app can be retrieved by browsing as in the following URLs:

- http://myapp-env-blablabla.elasticbeanstalk.com/static/requirements.txt
- http://myapp-env-blablabla.elasticbeanstalk.com/static/secrets/keys.py
- http://myapp-env-blablabla.elasticbeanstalk.com/static/myapp/services/some-app-logic.py
- etc

I poked around and found that this is caused by this config in the file **/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf**:

```
Alias /static /opt/python/current/app/ 
<Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Basically this allows read access to my entire app (deployed at **/opt/python/current/app/**) through the **/static** virtual path.

At this point someone might suggest that it's a simple matter of overriding the default Python container **staticFiles** option (what a terrible default value, by the way) using a .config ebextension file. Well, if you look at my directory structure, you'll see **python-container.config**, which has:

```
"aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "app/myapp/static/"
```

But this file is completely ignored when the Apache configuration files are generated. To (I think) prove that, look at the AWS EB scripts at these files (just the important lines):

**/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/pre/01generate.py**:

```py
configuration = config.SimplifiedConfigLoader().load_config()
config.generate_apache_config(
    configuration, os.path.join(config.ON_DECK_DIR, 'wsgi.conf'))
```

**/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/04configen.py**:

```py
configuration = config.SimplifiedConfigLoader().load_config()
config.generate_apache_config(
    configuration, os.path.join(config.ON_DECK_DIR, 'wsgi.conf'))
```

**/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/config.py**:

```py
def _generate_static_file_config(mapping):
    contents = []
    for key, value in mapping.items():
        contents.append('Alias %s %s' % (key, os.path.join(APP_DIR, value)))
        contents.append('<Directory %s>' % os.path.join(APP_DIR, value))
        contents.append('Order allow,deny')
        contents.append('Allow from all')
        contents.append('</Directory>')
        contents.append('')
    return '\n'.join(contents)

class SimplifiedConfigLoader(ContainerConfigLoader):
    def load_config(self):
        parsed = json.loads("path/to/containerconfiguration")
        python_section = parsed['python']
        converted = {}
        #..snip...
        static_files = {}
        for keyval in python_section['static_files']:
            key, value = keyval.split('=', 1)
            static_files[key] = value
        converted['static_files'] = static_files
        #...
        return converted
```

**/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/configuration/containerconfiguration**:

```
{
    "python": {
        //...
        "static_files": [
            "/static="
        ], 
        //...
}
```

I apologize for dumping so much code, but the gist of it is that when `_generate_static_file_config` is called to produce that part of *wsgi.config*, it never uses any of the values specified in those ebextension config files. `SimplifiedConfigLoader` only uses the fixed file *containerconfiguration*, which has the evil default value for the */static* mapping.

I hope I'm missing something because I can't find a way to prevent this without resorting to a custom AMI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up opening a paid case with AWS support and they confirmed it was a bug in the Python container code.

As a result of this problem, they have just released (10/25/2013) a new version of the container and any new environments will contain the fix. To fix any of your existing environments... well, you can't. You'll have to create a new environment from the ground up (don't even use saved configurations) and then switch over from the old one.

Hope this helps the next poor soul.

**Update 2017-01-10**: Back when I answered it wasn't possible to upgrade the container to newer versions. Since then AWS added that feature. You can even let it auto-update with the *Managed Platform Updates* feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the value of the said `/static` alias via the configuration console on your Elastic Beanstalk environment. Under the "Static Files" section, map the virtual path */static* to point to your directory *app/myapp/static/*

Comment: I mention this in my question. It wasn't working, which goes against the docs. That seemed the correct route but it was being ignored by the EB internal scripts when creating the Apache config. This was fixed by AWS in late October 2013.